# Having trouble with special characters in a string, super hard coding challenge problem

Tags: python, string, char

### **I have to check the validity of a string with the following rules:**

**There are 3 special characters: $ # ^**

- They cannot be next to each other in a string (ignoring spaces) except with the number/pound/hash character (#).

  - The # character can appear after another special character but only one.
- There must be a number before and after a special character, except with the # character if there is a number after it. However if there are two, there must be a number before the two #s.

  - "#5" is **valid**
  - "##5" is **invalid**
  - "5##5" is **valid**
- If there are only special characters in the string, it is automatically invalid.
- If there is only ONE number in the string it is valid. If there are multiple numbers separated by spaces, the string is no longer valid.

  - e.g. "25   40" is **invalid since 25 and 40 are seperated by a space**
  - "25" is **valid**

**You can assume you will get a string with only numbers and/or these special characters.**

**You can assume you will not get any zeroes in the string such as 0#0 or hanging zeroes like: 0.000, 00004 or 4.000**

**Treat all numbers the same, so .4 is a number and it works the same as 0.4 or 5 or 3.2 or 9231, etc.**

You can assume numbers are not in scientific notation or any other special number, only ones are shown here. No negative numbers.

### Examples of valid strings:

- "#5 #5 #5"
- "5 ^5.321 $#2.6"
- "5^#4.5"
- "#5#5#5"
- "56.2"

### Examples of invalid strings:

- "5 6" **(reason: separated by a space)**
- "5^^5" **(reason: two special characters next to each other)**
- "5^^^##5" **(reason: way too many special characters next to each other)**
- "^5" **(reason: no number before "^")**
- "^5&" **(reason: no number before "^" AND no number after "&")**

---

Here's my attempt:

```
def checkvalid(string1):
    string1 = string1.replace(" ", "")
    checkStatements = ["$$", "#$", "###", "^^", "#^"]
    checkOut = [x for x in checkStatements if x not in string1]
    if len(checkOut) != len(checkStatements):
        return False
    return True
```

It works for some of them, which is quite obvious since it only checks for specific patterns but for others such as:

- print(checkvalid("5##5  5"))
- print(checkvalid("5$$$"))
- print(checkvalid("$$$"))
- print(checkvalid("$5"))

My code returns "True" on all of them despite that these are all invalid so my code should return False. I am having trouble accounting for the fact that operators can't be next to each other and checking for a number before or after a special character.

Comment: Your code can't work because it only checks for those specific patterns and doesn't account for the fact that it could be #### or ############### etc...

Comment: @GaryWayne yea I said that in my question

Comment: You could split the string on special chacracter and then check for each element of the resulting list if the previous and next element are valid

Comment: What about negative numbers (`-1`) or scientific notation (`1e-3`)?

Comment: @ThomaS that would take a lot of lines of code for every possibility I assume.

Comment: what makes this hard is not being able to use exec or eval,

Comment: The word 'numbers' in the specification is ambiguous, making the specification ambigous.  Digits `[0-9]` would not be.  Or the same with '.' added.  Are ',' , '_', and others allowed?  Digits in other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this is correct answer, because the problem is slightly unclear. But check this:

```
import re
def checkvalid(string1):
    if re.search(r'[\d.]\s+[\d.]', string1): return False # two numbers separated by spaces
    string1 = string1.replace(' ', '')
    return (bool(re.search(r'\d', string1))               # must contain numbers
        and not re.search(r'\.\d*\.', string1)            # a number can't contain two dots
        and not re.search(r'[$^]{2}|#[$^]|[$^]#[$^#]', string1) # obviously
        and not re.search(r'^[$^]|[$^]$', string1)        # special at the beginning or end
        and not re.search(r'^##|##$', string1)            # two hashes at the beginning or end
    )
```

Comment: Erm, wait. You said **There are 3 special characters: $ # ^** - `&` isn't one of them. You also said **You can assume you will get a string with only numbers and/or these special characters.** so I assumed exactly that. So are we in fact talking about **4** special characters `# $ & ^`?

Comment: `None` is technically `False`, but if you want it explicitly, see the edit.

Comment: Wait actually it's still failing one test: "5###5" whenever there's more than two "#"s your code still returns true when it should return false. I fixed it by adding    
 |[#]{3} in the second re.search line

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches all listed failling cases :

`([$^]{2,}|\d +\d|(?<!\w )[$^]\d)` [With Examples](https://regex101.com/r/GyIHRW/2)

There are still many edgecases missing and this whole problem might not even be solvable with regexes but it's a decent start.
You might get into in issue with the negative lookbehind as thoses can't have a non-fixed width.

```regex
(
    [$^]{2,}        // two special characters
    |               // or
    \d +\d          // two numbers separated by space(s)
    |
    (?<!\d )[$^]\d  // a special char then a number not preceded by a special character
)
```

Comment: I don't think so - what about `^#` or `####`? Your regex doesn't match these.

Comment: As i said, there are still many edgecases missing, I'm at work right now ill try to fix them at home :)

Comment: thanks for trying, even work can't stop you. means a lot.